# option:first-child isn't selecting the same in all cases

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Why doesn't this work when a `select` has optgroups in it?

doesn't work

```
$("option:first-child").attr("selected", "selected");
```

works

```
$("select>option:first-child").attr("selected", "selected");
```

When I do `$("select:eq(1) option:first-child").val()` it appears to be getting the right `option`, but when I call `attr()` it isn't picking the right one.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/7J2Yb/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you check the value of `$("option:first-child").length` you will notice that it is `5`. `:first-child` is selecting options that are the first child of their parent, which are:

```
<SELECT id='a'>
    <OPTION selected value=0>(all)</OPTION><!-- THIS ONE -->
    <OPTION value=1>A</OPTION>
    <OPTION value=2>B</OPTION>
    <OPTION value=3>C</OPTION>
</SELECT>

<SELECT id='b'>    
    <OPTION selected value=0>(all)</OPTION><!-- THIS ONE -->
    <optgroup label="A">
        <OPTION value=1>A</OPTION><!-- THIS ONE -->
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="B">
        <OPTION value=2>B</OPTION><!-- THIS ONE -->
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="C">
        <OPTION value=3>C</OPTION><!-- THIS ONE -->
    </optgroup>
</SELECT>
```

Furthermore `$("select:eq(1) option:first-child").length` is equal to `4` for the same reason above. Calling `.val()` on the array outputs the first elements value, but the selector is selecting all 4 of them.

---

If you want to select the first element in each `select` write:

```
$("select").find("option:first").attr("selected", true);
```

**working example: http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/7J2Yb/2/**

Comment: Arg! I knew `val()` was returning the first value. Brain fart was telling me the `.attr("selected")` was setting the value of the first also. Stupid farts. Thanks!